# Renaming variables within a function for multiple tables

Tags: r, dataframe, function, for-loop

I'm trying to rename multiple variables which show up in a few different files I'm working with. In this example I'll just provide one row for the rule. Here's the code:

```
renaming <- function(dataset){
names(dataset)[names(dataset)=="Lookup Code...3"]<-"Recipient Code"
.
.
.
}
data <- read_excel("File.xlsx",sheet = "Sheet name")
renaming(data)
```

In the above example I am passing through one dataset. At this point the variable is not being renamed. I'm only new to making functions in R so maybe my syntax is off somewhere.

Once that problem is resolved I would like to then be able to pass a list into this function. I would like to do this by using a for loop which would look something like this:

```
dataset_list <- c("Data","Data_1",...)    

for(i in 1:length(dataset_list)){

renaming(dataset_list[i])

}
```

I made an attempt at a for loop similar to this but the dataset doesn't seem to get picked up in order to be passed into the function.

I appreciate the help and if you need clarification on this please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try -

```
renaming <- function(dataset){
  names(dataset)[names(dataset)=="Lookup Code...3"]<-"Recipient Code"
  #Some other code
  #Some more code
  #Return the changed dataset
  dataset
}
#Get all the filenames in a vector
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '.xlsx')

#apply the function to each file
list_data <- lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  renaming(readxl::read_excel(x))
})
```

`list_data` would have list of dataframes where each dataframe should have the changed column name and other code applied as written in `renaming` function. You can access individual dataframes using `list_data[[1]]`, `list_data[[2]]` etc.

Comment: Hi Ronak, that's a good solution for the for loop section of the issue. However, I'm still having a strange issue where after the dataset within the function has the new names but the table itself does not. Almost as if the changes are not saved outside of the function.

Comment: Here's a better example using mtcars from R:

Data = mtcars

renaming_cars<- function(datasets){
  names(datasets)[names(datasets)=="mpg"]<-"Miles per gallon"
  names(datasets)[names(datasets)=="cyl"]<-"Cylinders"
  datasets # This is where we see that the names have correctly changed to what's stated above
}

renaming_cars(Data)
Data # However here we see that these changes have reverted back to their initial names.

Comment: @AntoKiernan Yes, things changed inside function do not reflect outside it and we should also not try to do that. You should do `Data <- renaming_cars(Data)` which will change `Data`.